# \newcommand eating white spaces

Tags: macros

When creating a custom command, a simple *shortcut for a text string*, I get an undesired side effect

```
\newcommand{\test}{test}
```

Here the source

```
\test some text
\\
\test , some text
```

and the current output

```
testsome text
test, some text
```

How can I prevent the command from "eating" the white-space?

Comment: you can use `\test{} some text` instead of `\test some text`. Another solution is the xspace package : https://ctan.org/pkg/xspace